# Blue Pelican Java Textbook Lesson 17 Project AddEmUp

Tags: java

So my teacher gave me an assignment to do (will be shown below) and I tried to do it but just could not figure it out, here's the assignment:

Consider the following program that allows something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 + 137 to be entered as String input from the keyboard, A Scanner object then uses the plus signs (and any adjoining white space) as delimiters and produces the sum of these numbers (1523).

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*; 

public class Tester 

{ 

 public static void main(String args[]) 

 { 

 Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in); 



 System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1,345 +137 : "); 

 String s = kb.nextLine( ); //Best to store in a String and then create a new Scanner 

 //object; otherwise, it can get stuck waiting for input. 

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(s); 

 //Set delimiters to a plus sign surrounded by any amount of white space...or... 

 // a minus sign surrounded by any amount of white space. 

 sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*"); 



 int sum = 0; 

 while(sc.hasNextInt( )) 

 { 

 sum = sum + sc.nextInt( ); 

 } 

 System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); 



 } 

}
```

Now modify the program as to allow either plus or minus signs

^^^THAT WAS THE ASSIGNMENT^^^

Here is my source code:

```
//I can't get it to work if I use subtraction and addition at the same time but they work separately

import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddEmUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Here we create a String
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 - 137 : ");
        String s = kb.nextLine();

        //Now we convert the String to a scanner because we will be using Scanner methods
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);

        //Creates sum
        int sum = 0;

        //Does it's magic if it is addition
        if (s.contains("+")) {
            sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*");
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sum + sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //Does it's magic if it is subtraction
        if (s.contains("-")) {
            sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\-\\s*");
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                sum = sc.nextInt();
                sum = sum - sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        //Prints the magic
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me solve the problem (First comment in my source code)???

Comment: an Assignment ? :/

Comment: Yes. I'm a freshman in Highschool and that was the assignment for my computer science class

Comment: do you familiar with loops ?

Comment: your code is not gonna work , because you are checking the operators in wrong way !

Comment: Yes, at least with for loops, while loops, and do-while loops that is.

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: s.contains('+') always returns true , if your expression has a single '+'

Comment: Is it supposed to handle inputs with mixed operators, such as 1+45-7?

Comment: Yes, that's where my problem is. I cannot get it to use mixed operators.

Comment: @SEANCANTWELL are you familiar with arrays, or is that a topic you haven't covered yet?

Comment: I am not familiar with arrays, sorry.

Comment: @SEANCANTWELL, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to help you answer this in a way that's (hopefully) consistent with what you've learned so far. Since you haven't learned about arrays yet and are working with a `Scanner` with a delimiter pattern, we'll have to work around this constraint.

First, for the purposes of a school assignment, we can probably safely assume that your inputs will follow a particular pattern, along the lines of: `(number)(operator)(number)(operator)(number)...` and so on; additionally, you're probably not worried about input checking (making sure there are no letters/symbols/etc) or negative numbers, so we'll ignore those scenarios. Since you are only dealing with `+` and `-`, your delimiters are `"\\s*\\+\\s*"` and `"\\s*\\-\\s*"`, respectively. Since these values don't change (they are constants), and (in a real program) would be used multiple times in different places, we typically store these in their own `final` variables:

```
final String PLUS = "\\s*\\+\\s*"; // by convention, constants in java are named with all caps
final String MINUS = "\\s*\\-\\s*";
```

Now, let's look at your sample input: `8 + 33 + 1345 - 137`. How can you account for mixed operators?

```
int sum = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s); // s = "8 + 33 + 1345 - 137"
//What now?
```

You can still pull this off with one loop, but it will require some intermediate steps.

```
// start with +
sc.useDelimiter(PLUS);
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String temp = sc.next();
}
// first pass, temp = "8"
// first pass, temp = "3"
// first pass, temp = "1345 - 137" (!!!)
```

In the above example, `temp` would first be `"8"` (note that it's a `String` here), then `"33"` on the next pass, then `"1345 - 137"` on the third pass. You would typically use `Integer.parseInt()` to turn a `String` to an `int`, like so:

```
// start with +
sc.useDelimiter(PLUS);
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String temp = sc.next();
    sum += Integer.parseInt(temp);
}
// first pass, temp = "8"
// first pass, temp = "3"
// first pass, temp = "1345 - 137", code breaks at Integer.parseInt(temp)
```

However, this code breaks on the third pass, because `"1345 - 137"` is clearly not an integer value. This is where storing the value in `temp` comes into play; you can use a nested loop to evaluate subtraction portions of your expression! You were on the right track with checking for `+` and `-` in the input, and here is a more appropriate spot to use it:

```
// start with +
sc.useDelimiter(PLUS);
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String temp = sc.next();
    // check if there are - signs in temp
    if(temp.contains("-")){
        // if there are, evaluate the subtraction expression
        // for this example, temp = "1345 - 137"
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(temp);
        sc2.useDelimiter(MINUS);
        int diff = sc2.nextInt(); // diff = 1345
        while(sc2.hasNext()){
            diff -= sc2.nextInt(); // diff = 1345 - 137 = 1208
        }
        sum += diff; // adds the result to the sum
    } else {
        sum += Integer.parseInt(temp); // there is no - sign, so skip ahead and just add to the sum
    }
}
```

---

You'll notice I didn't check if the input contains a `+` sign at the beginning before the loop; this is because I'm assuming that even if you enter something like `1 - 5 - 9`, the Scanner will still return at least that whole string when `sc.next()` is called, which will still go into the inner loop, and the expression will still be evaluated. I haven't used a `Scanner` in a very long time, so if this assumption is incorrect, you'll have to fix that.